# Is there a maximum payload size that we can GET through MongoDB Atlas?

Tags: mongodb, rest

I have a document store on MongoDB Atlas where each document is roughly 1MB. I am using REST API and a GET request to access data from this database. This GET request filters the database and can return a bunch of documents based on the filter.

My question is : Is there a recommended payload size limit in terms of amount of data that we can transmit? For example if my filter results in 100 documents I would be transmitting approx 100MB of data.

Are there better ways to do this?

Comment: Short answer is no, no recommended size. it is up to you on what works best for you. however it's usually easier to process smaller batches, especially if you're doing it via REST.